# animation and keyframes not working in firefox

Tags: html, css

I have been having trouble making my site work across all major browsers, and I have become stuck once again. My keyframes animation does not run in Firefox, and I cannot work out why. It works perfectly in Chrome.

```
.runner {
    border-radius: 40pt;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey;
    width:494px;
    height: 415.8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0; 
    background: url(pic1.png);
    -webkit-animation: slideshow 20s infinite 2s;
       -moz-animation: slideshow 20s infinite 2s;
            animation: slideshow 20s infinite 2s;
}

@keyframes slideshow {
    20%      { background: url(pic1.png) }
    25%, 45% { background: url(pic2.png) }
    50%, 70% { background: url(pic3.png) }
    75%, 95% { background: url(pic4.png) }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideshow {
    20%      { background: url(pic1.png) }
    25%, 45% { background: url(pic2.png) }
    50%, 70% { background: url(pic3.png) }
    75%, 95% { background: url(pic4.png) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am using Firefox 28.

Below is the tutorial from W3 schools. **So i believe it's worth having a look.**

[CSS3 Animation Property try out](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation)

One thing is that, I think tutorial has been updated and -moz- link does not seem to be there.
So, as far as compatibility is concerned, the jurassic versions of IE and Firefox 3.5 and before may produce problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the -moz-animation prefix [anymore](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation), but you do need to add prefixes on the keyframes(@-moz-keyframes).